# How to properly loop through cells of a table view and add the objects from the array to a new array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Ok so I have very little experience with programming so please be patient. Let me explain further...I have a player class that has different properties. In the table view I number first name and last name of the player. I want to loop through each cell, and take the number first name and last name and add it to a new array. I don't want to be just add them as strings. I want to put them into a pickerview after ward. I have an dictionary that matches each number to a player ID. How would i do all of this? I have a loop that goes through tableviewcells which is like this

```
for (_tableViewCell in self.homePlayers.visibleCells)

    {
        if (_tableViewCell.accessoryType  == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        {
            [_homeConfirmedPlayersArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %@",_homePlayer.number,_homePlayer.firstName,_homePlayer.lastName]];
        }
    }
```

homePlayers is the tableView that I am looping through. The problem is that it does go through each cell but it only takes the data from the last cell and adds it the new array  once for each cell. I end up with 8 objects of the number first name and last name.

I set up the homePlauer object in cell for row at index path like this...

```
if ([tableView isEqual:self->_homePlayers])
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        //Step 1: Check to see if we can reuse cell from a row that is now off the screen.
        _tableViewCell = [_homePlayers dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        //Step 2: If no reusable cells create a new one
        if (_tableViewCell == nil)
        {
            _tableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        //Add detail view accessory

        _tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        //Step 3: Set up cell text

        _homePlayer = _homePlayersArray[indexPath.row];
        _tableViewCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %@",_homePlayer.number,_homePlayer.firstName,_homePlayer.lastName];


        //Step 4: Return the cell


        return _tableViewCell;
    }
```

If you need anymore information please ask. Thanks for the answers ahead of time!

Comment: You're mixing a lot of syntax by the way. C++ style is self->variable and self.variable, Obj-C style is [self variable]. Both work, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: It looks like you already have a data source for your tableview (_homePlayer) with all the data. So you don't have to try reading it from the table view, you can read it it from the data source directly. Picker view works in similar way, so you can use the same data as data source for the UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you did a problem a lot of new programmer do, globalize everything. _homePlayer looks like it should be a local variable. What I assume is happening is when the UITableView is populating itself by calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, the last cell that will be generated will set the global _homePlayer. Then when you other loop function gets called, _homePlayer will have already been set, and you also never change it in your loop function. That's why you get the same 8 objects. Here's how to fix it:

Make step 3 this:

```
id homePlayer = _homePlayersArray[indexPath.row];
tableViewCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %@", homePlayer.number, homePlayer.firstName, homePlayer.lastName];
```

You should replace 'id' with the homePlayer type so the compiler will assist you with auto completion.
I think you mentioned it was a NSDictionary, so replace id with `NSDictionary *`.

For your loop function do this: (comments for explanation)

```
// create a new and empty array
// (your local array will forever fill up with repeated objects unless emptied somewhere)
NSMutableArray *homeConfirmedPlayersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// loop through all indexpaths for the visible cells
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.homePlayers indexPathsForVisibleRows]){
    // get the tablecell, only to check the accessory type
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.homePlayers cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // I don't think this is necessary, especially if every cell has a checkmark
    if (cell.accessoryType  == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        // get the record from the home players array
        NSDictionary *homePlayer = _homePlayersArray[indexPath.row];

        // add to the copy
        [homeConfirmedPlayersArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %@",homePlayer.number,homePlayer.firstName,homePlayer.lastName]];
    }
}
```

Remember to only use global variables only when you need them to be global.

Comment: I think that I do need the homeConfirmedPlayersArray to be global because i need to use it later to populate my pickerView. Also homePlayer is a player object not a dictionary. I do have a dictionary already set that has an ID for an object that corresponds to a player number. I need to be able to choose the the name in the picker view and then take the number from it to find the id that corresponds. Would this work for what i want to do or would i have to change it?

Comment: I thought homePlayer was a custom object, I just didn't know what. I haven't worked with pickerviews, but with any view it should only display data not contain it (which should prevent the current problem). How ever you display the data, when the user selects something you should get an NSIndexPath which then you use to index you data array. When you populate the pickerview, use the indexpath.row as the index to select the item in your array. Then when a user selects a row, use the returned indexPath to match to the array.

Comment: I'll add, if the user IDs are only stored in a dictionary (best in your case), then you might want to consider a lookup array that matches indexPath.row to dictionary.key. Also I just looked up UIPickerView, so use selectedRowInComponent: instead of indexPath.row.